# speed up data access in a search form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

In a spring mvc app using hibernate and JPA, I have a `keyword` class which enables users to search records in an underlying database.  The JSP has a search box in a dandelion datatable, and the user types in text to reduce the number of `keyword` options, until the search results contain a short-enough list of `keywords` from which the user can select the word to use for their search.

**The problem is that there are 80,000 `keywords` in the underlying data table, and it takes 20 minutes for my app to send all those `keywords` to the JSP, even after I put an index on the underlying database table for the field used in the search.  Is there some way to set it up so that `keywords` are only sent to the JSP when at least 3 characters of text has been entered into the search box?**

Here is my `controller` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(
        ConcWordKey wordkey, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

    Collection<ConcWordKey> results = this.clinicService.findKeyWord("");
    System.out.println("results.size() is: "+results.size());
    model.put("selections", results);
    return "search";
}
```

And here is the relevant part of the JSP:

```
<datatables:table id="keywords" data="${selections}" cdn="true" row="kw" theme="bootstrap2" 
      cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="true" info="false" 
      cssStyle="width: 150px;" align="left" dom="frtp">
    <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 150px;" display="html">
        <spring:url value="/search?name={name}" var="searchUrl">
            <spring:param name="name" value="${kw.name}"/>
        </spring:url>
        <a href="${fn:escapeXml(searchUrl)}"><c:out value="${kw.name}"/></a>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

Here is the JPA method that populates the selections:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<ConcWordKey> findKeyWord(String str) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT wk FROM ConcWordKey wk WHERE wk.name LIKE :wd");
    query.setParameter("wd", str + "%");
    Collection<ConcWordKey> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Introduce paging and limit data per one page.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Thank you.  But can you show me how that would look in code?

Comment: @CodeMed one workaround i can suggest for time being until i go through dandelion datatable API. In your controller don't always call your DAO method if size is less than 3.call database to fetch result when entered keyword length is at least 3.meanwhile i search altimate soution for this

Comment: @Gautam Thank you very much.  But I am not even sure how to write the check for 3+ characters.

Comment: Like in your code Collection<ConcWordKey> results = this.clinicService.findKeyWord(inputString);  don't execute this line until  inputString size is less than 3

Comment: @Gautam Yes, I got that much.  But I don't know how to access the inputString in code.

Comment: @Gautam I tried iterating through `request.getModel()`, `request.getParamaterNames()`, and `request.getAttributeNames()`, but none of these return the input string.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @CodeMed i cheked some samples of datatables but i can see there is  client side filetering by default so you need to implement it sever side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the poor client-side performance come from the method your are using for loading the data. I think 80000 records is too much for a DOM source, especially with the search fired on keypress.

**Before the v0.10.0:**
I recommend you to switch to an [AJAX source](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/tutorials/ajax/) (with paging enabled). A bit more work is required to set things up but it should have a significant impact on performance.
Note that the [JSP sample](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-samples/tree/master/datatables-jsp) app does use the same technologies (Spring, JPA) as yours. Feel free to take a look.

However, if you really want to keep loading data with a DOM source, you could simply unbind the keypress event handler, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619498/datatables-global-search-on-keypress-of-enter-key-instead-of-any-key-keypress). To implement it, you'll need the [extra JavaScript feature](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/tutorials/advanced/using-extra-files.html) of Dandelion-Datatables.

**Starting from the v0.10.0:** the filtering feature has been improved in multiple ways:

- a [time delay](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/basics/filtering/delayed-filtering.html) (500ms by default, configurable) is always applied before firing the search
- a [min character length](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/basics/filtering/delayed-filtering.html#dfcb) can be also configured
- or you can fire the [search on a click event](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/basics/filtering/filtering-on-click.html) instead

Of course, using an AJAX source is still recommended but the above features will improve the UX even more. I'll update this anwser with the right links to the new docs and sample apps once this version released.

Hope this helps!

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I'm the author of Dandelion)*

EDIT: Dandelion 0.10.0 released. Links added

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to answer this.  I reviewed your links in detail.  For my immediate solution, I am doing a workaround instead, but I plan to carefully study your links as I develop a longer term solution.

Answer (score 0):

`EhCache` may not be what you need first. It provides ability to handle your application cache, which means keep in memory the most used objects, to access them faster (from memory rather then querying them) when you need them. So if you have like 80 000 keywords, that sounds like you have 80 000+ search possibilities, which means that :

- It'll take a lot of memory to keep them all in the cache
- You must search all of them once to have them in the cache

What you may need, though, is an underlying index system, like `Lucene` (or `Solar` if you have multiple instances), which will help you speed up your queries. Then, your searches will be faster, no matter they have been fired before or not.

Of course, you can use the indexing system with a caching system to have even better performances. My point is indexing would be more important than caching at first.

Some other ideas :

- Be sure to enable your database cache (lvl1 cache) so that your queries will be faster
- Add a database index on your keyword column (also speeds up a lots the select queries)

Good luck !

**EDIT** : Reviewing the problem, an autocomplete functionality would be better. For example : http://johnderinger.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/html-autocomplete-with-jpa-rest-and-jquery/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I added an index to the database, which is at least now giving some initial results to show the user it is doing something while the JSP freezes up.  But it is still too slow.  Can you show me a specific solution in code?

Comment: Well I re-read your question, and I would suggest you to use another approach. As I understand it you need to filter keywords so the user can choose from a light list. Giving the number of keywords you have, it may be better to use an autocomplete ability for example, which mean loading up only keywords that match what the user entered. So you'll load your page with no tag (very fast then), and load them asynchronously when the user types in. For better performance, only query your DB when he entered at least 3 or 4 characters. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds much better.  Thank you.  But I Have no idea how to put that into code.  Are you willing to demonstrate?

Comment: I edited my post. You have plenty of auto-complete example over the internet. This is a way to broad question to ask here. Though, while implementing it, if you experience specific issues with a specific part, feel free to create another question, and I'll be happy to help

Comment: Thank you, but I think you are making it more complex than it needs to be.  A search in the MySQL command line client using LIKE only takes 0.03 seconds to run.  The problem is that my code above is loading the entire list of keywords when the JSP first loads.  If you could show me how to get the spring databinding in the code above to only happen after the user has entered at least 3 characters, then this question would be answered.

Comment: Well, I don't really know about your datatable (never used it). I was answering your performance problems with solution I'm used to implement. While the principle stay the same, implementation may be a bit different for different solutions. Maybe you can find a dynamic table which already handles those asynchronous requests (which seems to be a reasonable guess). Sorry I can't help your more than that. Anyway, no matter what solution you implement, indexing will always be useful when dealing for multiple requests.